# Warning at sequelize magic association method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, webstorm

I'm having warning at sequelize magic method in my WebStorm IDE. The code running fine so there is no error in the code but the IDE just doesn't recognize it.

[image]

All other methods by sequilze are recognised by the IDE apart from this one. This is how I importing Sequelize

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize').Sequelize;

const sequelize = new Sequelize('test-schema', 'root', 'mypassword', {dialect: 'mysql', host: 'localhost'});
```

Here are my JS library in preferences

[image]

I tried to add new library `@types/sequelize` with no luck

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: it's still not clear what `createProduct` definition looks like, how it's accessed, etc. Please provide a full, self-containing code snippet (as text/link to github/...)

Comment: @lena createProduct methode is generated automatically by sequelize.. you can read more about it here https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/base.js~Association.html Like I said the code works but the IDE doesn't recognise it

Comment: @delmin I have had problem with this method as well in WebStorm so I was forced to use VSCode. Hopefully someone will answer your questions so I can go back to WebStorm again.. BTW don't let anyone provoke you here.. Just ignore them.. I don't think there is anything wrong with your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is not defined statically anywhere, it's generated dynamically in runtime. In such case, there is no way for the IDE to resolve it using static code analysis... You can disable WebStorm inspections if shutting them up, making the code 'green', is the only requirement. Like:

```
// noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
req.user.createProduct({
```

Recognizing such methods would require adding special support for Sequelize by developing a plugin. You can find basic documentation about plugin development here: http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/. Some open source plugins can be found at https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins.

I can also suggedst filing a feature request for providing Sequelize support to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Thanks for the answer... really appreciate that